# Execute one function after other has executed Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, promise

I have this `createCal` method in `ngOninit` after `createCal` is executed i want to execute `createDefault()`  after loop is executed three times then other codes should execute that are after `createCal`. Getting warning message `let res=await this.createDefault();` 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.createCal();
    ..
    }
    
     async createCal()
      {
        let response=await this.commonService.getAllList().toPromise();
        if(response?.length==0)
        {
          let res=await this.createDefault();
        }
      }
    
    
    
     createDefault()
      {
        let defaultList=['Test 1','Test 2','Test 3'];
        for(let i=0;i<defaultList.length;i++)
        {
          if(defaultList[i])
          {
            let Json =  {
              Id: defaultList[i],
            }
            this.commonService.create(Json).subscribe(async (x: any) => {  
         
            }) 
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all about what you wanna do...

But you need to make the `createDefault` async, too.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createCal();
    ..
    }
    
     async createCal()
      {
        let response = await this.commonService.getAllList().toPromise();
        if(response?.length === 0)
        {
          let res = await this.createDefault();
        }
      }
    
    
    
     async createDefault()
      {
        let defaultList=['Test 1','Test 2','Test 3'];
        for(let i=0;i<defaultList.length;i++)
        {
          if(defaultList[i])
          {
            let Json =  {
              Id: defaultList[i],
            }
            // Here you should use "toPromise", too, if you wanna wait...
            this.commonService.create(Json).subscribe(async (x: any) => {  
         
            }) 
          }
        }
      }
```

#### Note

`toPromise` is deprecated. The new function is `lastValueFrom`. Use it like this:

```
...
async createCal()
      {
        let response = await lastValueFrom(this.commonService.getAllList());
        if(response?.length === 0)
        {
          let res = await this.createDefault();
        }
      }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an error because the `createDefault` is not an async function. It would be so much better to decide on one approach - Promise or Observables based.

This is how you can do it without promises, by taking advantage of rxjs:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.commonService.getAllList().pipe(
    // checking if the response is empty
    filter(response => response?.length === 0),
    // if it is empty, then produce 3 "create" calls
    switchMap(() => {
      const defaultList = ['Test 1','Test 2','Test 3'];
      const jsonObjects = defaultList.map(id => ({Id: id}));

      return combineLatest(
        jsonObjects.map(json => this.commonService.create(json))
      );
    }),
  ).subscribe()
}
```